# Mysql Update Sequence Duplicate value

Tags: mysql

How to update sequence number

ask 1.

```
Column   | Desire
AAAAAA   | 1
AAAAAA   | 1
AAAAAA   | 1
BBBBBB   | 2
BBBBBB   | 2
BBBBBB   | 2
CCCCCC   | 3
CCCCCC   | 3
```

Ask 2

```
Column   | Desire
AAAAAA   | 1
AAAAAA   | 2
AAAAAA   | 3
BBBBBB   | 1
BBBBBB   | 2
BBBBBB   | 3
BBBBBB   | 4
CCCCCC   | 1
CCCCCC   | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DENSE_RANK()` function with `ORDER BY Column`:

```
SELECT Column,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Column) AS 'Desire'
FROM mytable;
```

returns:

| Column | Desire |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAAA | 1 |
| AAAAAA | 1 |
| AAAAAA | 1 |
| BBBBBB | 2 |
| BBBBBB | 2 |
| BBBBBB | 2 |
| CCCCCC | 3 |
| CCCCCC | 3 |

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` function with `PARTITION BY Column`:

```
SELECT Column,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column) AS 'Desire'
FROM mytable;
```

returns:

| Column | Desire |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAAA | 1 |
| AAAAAA | 2 |
| AAAAAA | 3 |
| BBBBBB | 1 |
| BBBBBB | 2 |
| BBBBBB | 3 |
| BBBBBB | 4 |
| CCCCCC | 1 |
| CCCCCC | 2 |

Comment: This is help for me, thanks